# Why I'm not able to connect to HBase running as Docker container?

Tags: java, spring, docker, hbase

I have my Java Spring app that deals with HBase.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class HbaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HbaseTemplate hbaseTemplate(@Value("${hadoop.home.dir}") final String hadoopHome,
                                       @Value("${hbase.zookeeper.quorum}") final String quorum,
                                       @Value("${hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort}") final String port)
            throws IOException, ServiceException {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", hadoopHome);
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", quorum);
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", port);
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(configuration);
        return new HbaseTemplate(configuration);
    }

}

#HBASE
hbase.zookeeper.quorum = localhost
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort = 2181
hadoop.home.dir = C:/hadoop
```

Before asking the question I tried to figure out the problem on my own and found this link https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase.docker

But still, I get an error

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 10000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=myhbase/192.168.99.100:60000]
```

Could I ask you to help me and clarify how can I connect my local Java app with HBase running in Docker?

Comment: would help to see your docker-compose or dockerfile

Comment: I run my Java app via Gradle or Intellij Idea. Why do I need rocket compose?

Comment: you're running this in docker containers, right?  you need a docker file and/or docker compose to define the containers/ports/other configuration

Comment: I run in Docker container only HBase image from the provided link

Comment: Is HBase on the same machine as your java code?

Comment: Yes, Windows laptop

Comment: You need to show your docker run command